# Rank ANCOVA is a bad idea?

Tags: regression, nonparametric

I am currently working on a project looking at the best way to handle missing data (such as quality of life) due to death. One approach is to use categories/ranks for the outcome, where death is the worst category. One approach that my colleagues wish to consider is rank ANCOVA. However I am pleased to say that they also wish to consider proportional odds models and continuation ratio models.

I found an R help page that says “This [rank ANCOVA] has been shown to yield unreliable analyses. Use the more formal proportional odds ordinal logistic model. This is a generalization of the Wilcoxon-Mann-Whitney-Kruskal-Wallis statistic. This is implemented in the rms package and elsewhere”.

My question is this: Could anyone tell me where this has been shown? In particular the part about rank ancova being unreliable?

Answer (score 4):

This paper may be a good one demonstrating problems with rank transform anova: https://www.tandfonline.com/doi/abs/10.1080/01621459.1995.10476644
https://www.jstor.org/stable/2291530?seq=1#metadata_info_tab_contents

Just transforming data with ranks and using ordinary regression/anova/ancova, in cases other than the k-sample problem, i.e., attempting to use this when adjusting for covariates or assessing interactions, is not fully based on good statistical principles, and results are hard to interpret.